# What is the limit of |x| as x approaches 0?

Tags: calculus, limits

Alright, I feel like this is simpler than I think it is...

So the limit we want to know is $$\lim_{x \to 0}  f(x)=|x|$$

First we look at the piecewise definition which is given by $$|x| = \begin{cases}
x,  & x\geqslant 0 \\
-x, & x\lt0
\end{cases}$$

We then look at the one sided limits, for the limit to 0 from above, we consider the case where $$x\geqslant 0$$ such that $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}  x$$ Yet this leaves us with just an x, which as it goes to 0... is 0? Yet the solutions I have calculate it in the followin way, $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}  \frac{|x|}{x} = 1$$

Why is it divided by x, where does that come from? And furthermore, why does it approach 1 when there are other numbers that exist between 1 and 0 that x could approach... I guess I'm also missing an intuitive understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the limit to exist, you need the side limits to commute. In this case :

$$\lim_{x \to 0} |x| = \lim_{x \to 0} |x| = \begin{cases} \lim_{x\to 0^+} x, \space x  \geq 0 \\ \lim_{x \to 0^-} -x, \space x<0\end{cases} = \begin{cases} 0, \space x \geq 0 \\ 0, \space x <0 \end{cases}$$

which means that the side limits are equal and thus : $\lim_{x \to 0}  |x| = 0$.

As far as the $\frac{|x|}{x}$ part, if you divide something by a quantity, you will also need to multiply it by that. This is why you're getting $1$ as a wrong answer there.

Comment: But if a limit exists and is 0, doesn't this imply the function is differentiable at that point, which, by looking at the graph of |x| should not be the case?

Comment: @Davin How did the "differentiable" thing pop up ? Weren't we just looking to calculate the limit ? And no, your statement is wrong, this **does not** imply that the function is differentiable at the point. The limits you need to check for differentiability, are : $$\lim_{x \to x_0} = \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ This is **not** the same as just $$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$$

Comment: I see now, the solutions I have were written incorrectly but yes I see now that only taking the limit of the function shows it is continuous but taking the limit of the derivative shows there is a disparity as -1 doesn't equal 1 aka the slopes don't match up and the derivative DNE... Thanks, that's cleared things up

Answer (score 1):

You have $\lim_{x\to0}|x|=0$ because, for every $\varepsilon>0$, if you take $\delta=\varepsilon$, then$$|x|<\delta\implies|x|<\varepsilon\iff\bigl||x|-0\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$